# ASP.NET MVC: passing a complex viewmodel to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, model-binding, kendo-treeview

firs of all i searched for my question but couldnt find anything that helped me get any further.

i am trying to implement a view which allows me to set permissions for the current user.

As the data-structure i use following recursive class where each PermissionTree-Object references the sub-permissions (permissions are hierarchically structured in my application) :

```
public class PermissionTree
{
        public Permission Node; //the permission object contains a field of type SqlHierarchyId if that is relevant
        public bool HasPermission;
        public IList<PermissionTree> Children;
   //i cut out the constructors to keep it short ...
}
```

here is how the controller looks like:

```
//this is called to open the view
 public ActionResult Permissions()
    {
        //pass the root element which contains all permission elements as children (recursion)
        PermissionTree permissionTree = PopulateTree();//the fully populated permission-tree
        return View(permissionTree);
    }

//this is called when i submit the form
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Permissions(PermissionTree model)
    {
        SetPermissions(model);
        ViewData["PermissionsSaved"] = true;

        return View(model);//return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

in am using a strongly typed view like this:

```
@model PermissionTree
//....
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Permissions", "Permission", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "stdform stdform2" }))
{    
<input name="save" title="save2" class="k-button" type="submit" />

<div class="treeview">
//i am using the telerik kendoUI treeview
    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
            .Name("Permissions")
            .Animation(true)
            .ExpandAll(true)
            .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                .CheckChildren(true)
            )
            .BindTo(Model, mapping => mapping
                .For<PermissionTree>(binding => binding
                .Children(c => c.Children)
                .ItemDataBound( (item, c) => {
                    item.Text = c.Node.PermissionName;
                    item.Checked = c.HasPermission;
                })

                )
            )
      )
```

ok, so when i click the button, i want my viewmodel to be sent to the controller action that is decorated with `[HttpPost]`. But when i debug the application, the received model does not really contain my data (it is not null though).
Does anyone know how i can achieve my goal and get the whole viewmodel?

best regards,
r3try

Comment: Have you any input fields in your view?

Comment: no, i only use a treeview with checkboxes

Comment: Try seeing what's happening in the model binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651085/best-practices-for-debugging-asp-net-mvc-binding

Comment: @r3try Well then, that's your problem. What's passed as parameters in your action methods when submitting is **only the list of input fields**. You could try to add `@Html.HiddenFor(z => z.HasPermission)` in your view, you'll see that it'll be passed as parameter in your controller. Do you really need to get that from the view, isn't the `PermissionTree` object available on server-side?

Comment: the thing is that i want to let the user check/uncheck permissions in the tree and i need that information (the final set of selections) in my controller to persist it to the database. or am i approaching this task from a totally wrong side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use a JSON post here ,then it's easy to prepare the object in the javascript side.

I don't know how your HTML looks like or the names of the elements you can easyly use javascript/Jquery to build the client side json object with similar names and slimier hierarchy/dataTypes just like in the `PermissionTree` class. And then use Ajax post to post as JSON

```
 var PermissionTree={Node:{},HasPermission:false,Children:{}}
 $.ajax({  data:PermissionTree
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'YourController/Permissions',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (result) {   
               }
);
```

The important thing is you need to find a better way of going throuth the tree view and build the object in javascript.

Comment: i think i dont fully understand this...
you mean when i click the submit button i should use javascript to create the serialized object manually and then post the data to my controller using ajax? i really dont understand why there are strongly typed views in mvc when you cant even pass that viewmodel back to the controller. isnt that the point of views to modify the model? .. \*sigh\*   frustration aside - thanks for your reply! ;)

Comment: The issue is with the collection of models you have. To post strongly types view and to populate model you need to have a proper naming conventions used in the view. I mean in the HTML your inputs should have names like `Children[0].Chilren[1].Permission` as an example.

Comment: If you don't have that the best way is to populate a JSON object and pass it using Ajax.

Comment: i am trying to do what you said is necessary for the automatic model binding to work (the naming conventions).
how can i set up my kendo treeview so that this requirement is fullfilled?

Comment: I think you can write some jquery to update names in the nodes in a correct way before submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

as i cant get that to work i was trying a slightly different approach:

example for adding a node:
- press add button -> execute ajax call -> add the node in nhibernate -> call the view again with the new data (the new node included)

controller-action that is called by the ajax request:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPermission(string parentPermissionName, string permissionName)
    {
        var pd = ServiceContext.PermissionService.permissionDao;
        Permission parentPermission = pd.GetPermissionByName(parentPermissionName);
        if (parentPermission == null) {
            parentPermission = pd.GetRoot();
        }

        if (parentPermission != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(permissionName) && !pd.PermissionExists(permissionName))//only add with a name
        {
            pd.AddPermission(parentPermission, permissionName);
        }
        //refresh data
        PermissionTree permissionTree = LoadTreeSQLHierarchy(null, false);//start at root
        return View("Permissions", permissionTree);
    }
```

Ajax Request in the View:

```
function addNode() {
    //... get the data here
    var addData = { parentPermissionName: selectedNodeName, permissionName: newNodeName };

    $.ajax(
       {
           data: addData,
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("AddPermission", "Permission")',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) {
               //$('.centercontent').html(response);//load to main div (?)
               return false;
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(xhr.status + ":" + thrownError);
               return false;
           }
       }
    );
    return false;
}
```

But when i execute this i get an error stating that json.parse hit an invalid character (i get this error at the alert in the ajax's error function).
Judging from that message i would say that the problem is that i am returning html but the ajax call expects json or so...
But what is the correct way to just reload my view with the new data? Can i somehow tell the ajax call to not go back at all and just execute the called controller-method?