# MVC 4 Modelbinding with collection and enum same prefix - collection is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, model-binding

I'm having a problem with my MVC 4 project (it's part of a sitefinity web app) binding the model properly.  It all works fine until I introduce the MembershipType enum into the view.  The enum binds correctly but the Members collection is always null.  Just the presence of the enum seems to trigger the problem.  It doesn't matter if I use a textbox, dropdownlist or hidden input. After commenting out the enum the collection will bind successfully again. 
When the Members collection is null the modelstate is valid with no errors just with no entries for the members attributes. 
All the form values are posted and seem to be in the correct format.

Does anyone know why binding a collection could break or how to step through the binding?  Is there an alternative method for posting collections in a model?

Here are some code details:

```
 public class Membership
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UrlName { get; set; }
        public string MembershipNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string PostalAddressee { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    }



 public enum MembershipType{
        Single,
        Bonsai,
        ConcessionX2,
        Life,
        Donation,
        ExMember,
        Deceased,
        Association,
        Corporate,
        Concession,
        NotFinancial,
        Household,
        NoCost,
        NonMember
    }

    public class Member
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid MembershipId { get; set; }
        public string UrlName { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool OptOutOfEmail { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Detail(Membership membership)
        {
            ...
        }
```

view:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("Detail", "Membership", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "editMemberForm", role = "form" }))
{
    foreach (var member in Model.Members)
    {
        int i = 0;
        <h1>@member.Title @member.FirstName @member.LastName</h1>

        <label>
            Title:
            @Html.TextBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].Title", @Model.Members[i].Title)
        </label>

        <label>
            First Name:
            @Html.TextBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].FirstName", @Model.Members[i].FirstName)
        </label>

        <label>
            Last Name:
            @Html.TextBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].LastName", @Model.Members[i].LastName)
        </label>
        <label>
            Email:
            @Html.TextBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].Email", @Model.Members[i].Email)
        </label>
        <label>
            Opt out of Email:
            @Html.CheckBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].OptOutOfEmail", @Model.Members[i].OptOutOfEmail)
        </label>
        <label>
            Founding Member:
            @Html.CheckBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].FoundingMember", @Model.Members[i].FoundingMember)
        </label>
        <label>
            Council Member:
            @Html.CheckBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].CouncilMember", @Model.Members[i].CouncilMember)
        </label>
        <label>
            Trained Arboretum Guide:
            @Html.CheckBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].TrainedArboretumGuide", @Model.Members[i].TrainedArboretumGuide)
        </label>
        <label>
            Bonsai Guide:
            @Html.CheckBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].BonsaiGuide", @Model.Members[i].BonsaiGuide)
        </label>
        <label>
            Vulnerable People Number:
            @Html.TextBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].VulnerablePeopleNumber", @Model.Members[i].VulnerablePeopleNumber)
        </label>
        <label>
            VPN Expiry Date:
            @Html.TextBox("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].VulnerablePeopleExpiry", (Model.Members[i].VulnerablePeopleExpiry == null) ? "" : ((DateTime)Model.Members[i].VulnerablePeopleExpiry).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), new { @class = "vpnExp" })
        </label>
        @Html.Hidden("Members[" + i.ToString() + "].Id", @Model.Members[i].Id)
    }
    <label>
        Expiry Date:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpiryDate, new { Value = Model.ExpiryDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") })
    </label>

    <label>
        Membership Number:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MembershipNumber)
    </label>
    @*<label>
        Membership Type:
        @Html.DropDownList("MembershipType", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SitefinityWebApp.MembershipType)).Cast<SitefinityWebApp.MembershipType>()))
    </label>*@
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MembershipType);*@
    <input type="submit" />
```

Comment: OK i'm trying to step through using the method in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651085/best-practices-for-debugging-asp-net-mvc-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is actually a bug in the DefaultModelBinder in asp.net MVC 4.  A collection who's name is a prefix of a field name in the same class will fail to be found.  More details here:
http://rarelyupdated.azurewebsites.net/posts/5606734

I changed my

```
IList<Member> Members
```

to

```
IList<Member> People
```

and all is well.