# Unable to deserialize date in array of complex objects

Tags: json, ajax, datetime

On MVC side I have a class like this:

```
public class ComplexOne
{
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

And in controller action

```
public virtual JsonResult TakeData(int id, ComplexOne[] data)
```

From JS I'm sending object like this:

```
{
id = 10,
data = [
        {Date:"2017-12-27", Value:10},
        {Date:"2017-12-27", Value:20},
        {Date:"2017-12-27", Value:30}
    ]
}
```

MVC understands all except Date, which deserializes as default value (`{01.01.0001 0:00:00}`). I've tried different date formats - `yyyy-MM-dd`, `dd-MM-yyyy`, `MM/dd/yyyy` and even ISO one, but got no luck.

How to do this in correct way without passing date as string and manual parsing in MVC?

Comment: Because in your class you have DateTime object but you are passing date as string to deserialize.

Comment: There's no problem in other cases; even more in ISO format the full date and time are passed.

Comment: I think it expects date with time in the string. or try creating DateTime Object like 
`{Date: new DateTime(2015,06,27), Value: 10}`

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy Is that class shown exactly as how you have in your code? The shown class is 
private and has private fields. I am uncertain that what is shown binds to anything. Provide a [mcve] that represents the actual problem.

Comment: @varatharajan Then browser sends ugliest datetime string I've seen and again with no luck.

Comment: @Nkosi I'ts just a scheme, but I corrected it for you.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300811/728795) - may give you some idea of what's going on in model binding

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy okay. did you tried with timestamps ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `Date` as `string` in the `JSON` object but your `Date` in `ComplexOne` model class is `DateTime`.

So you can use `DTO` to receive the JSON object in the controller action and then convert the `DTO` to actual model as follows:

```
public class ComplexOneDto
{
   public string Date {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

The controller action:

```
public virtual JsonResult TakeData(int id, ComplexOneDto[] data)
{
    // here convert the ComplexOneDto[] to ComplexOne[] as follows

    List<ComplexOne> complexOnes = new List<ComplexOne>();
    foreach (ComplexOneDto complexOneDto in data)
    {
       DateTime convertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(complexOneDto.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       complexOnes .Add(new ComplexOne() { Date = convertedDateTime, Value = complexOneDto.Value });
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```